# Initiate rsync only if destination has enough space

Tags: linux, rsync, disk-usage

Is there any option in `rsync` to check whether having enough space in the destination before starting to sync data?

I checked the man page, but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. Rsync does not check the size of what you want to transfer before starting.